# How to overlay Glyphicon on image

Tags: html, css

I can't get my head around how to layer a Glyphicon (.glyphicon-
zoom-in) over a Bootstrap .img-thumbnail.

The css rule is -  content:"\e015";

Comment: Can you post your attempt please? (code)

Comment: you want icon should appear on :hover. http://jsbin.com/dasemikatube/1/edit

Answer (score 25):

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper"><img src="..."><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-leaf"></span><div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper {
   position: relative;
}

.wrapper .glyphicon {
   position: absolute;
   top: 20px;
   left: 40px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/idmean/7672Lt7L/1/ Sweet, isn't it?

Comment: Yay for the added sweetness :)